# Use of BlocProvider and instantiating the BLoC

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm quite a beginner with Flutter and started to learn about the BLoC pattern recently.

I don't understand why I need to use BlocProvider.of(context) inside widgets where I can simply instantiate a Bloc on top of the file where all the widgets rely (final blocX = bloc();), even without defining a single BlocProvider in any of the code.

Thank You very much.

```
class HomePageInit extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider(
        builder: (context) => WeatherBloc(),
        child: Homepage(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then inside the same file, outside any class or widget :

```
  final weatherBloc = WeatherBloc(),
```

Then inside widgets :

```
class SubmitButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SubmitButtonState createState() => _SubmitButtonState();
}

class _SubmitButtonState extends State<SubmitButton> {
  void submitCityName(String name) {

    weatherBloc.dispatch(GetWeather(name));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely Right. You could use a global variable, that would achieve the same purpose.

However, Flutter's idea is that everything is widget. using `BlocProvider.of(context)` fits with that philosophy. SOme may even say that global variable are evil, but that's speculation :)

Another usefull thing by using the `BlocProvider` Widget is that it lives in your widget tree, and is constructed only when needed. The global var however will tend to stay there, even if you don't need it.

So I encourage you to use the `BlocProvider` to have a code that fits in the global FLutter way to code.

Comment: Thank You so much, this makes sense now !